# Avoiding try/except when web-scraping html

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I was recently writing a web-scraper, and I found myself nesting try/except loops and relying on errors to drive part of my code like the following two segments:

```
try:
    reg_title = soup.find('p', {'class': "regnumber-e"}).text
except AttributeError:
    try:
        reg_title = soup.find('p', {'class': "regtitle-e"}).text
    except AttributeError:
        reg_title = soup.find('p', {'class': "Yregnumber-e"}).text
```

and

```
if soup.find_all('p', {'class': "Notice"}):
    try:
        #More code
    except IndexError:
        #More code
        continue
elif (soup.find_all('p', {'class': "ConsolidationPeriod-e"}) or
      soup.find_all('p', {'class': "ConsolidationPeriod"})):
    try:
        text = soup.find('p', {'class': "ConsolidationPeriod-e"}).text
    except AttributeError:
        text = soup.find('p', {'class': "ConsolidationPeriod"}).text
elif soup.find('p', {'class': "Notice-e"}):
    #More code
    continue
else:
    continue
```

Obviously I have cut out sections of code, but the specific code is irrelevant here. Generally, my poor coding sensors are going off and I feel like there has to be a better way to navigate differing html tags when web-scraping. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not just `try except`all your code catching multi exception? Like:

```
try:
    # All your code
    # For exemple 
    # if soup.find_all('p', {'class': "Notice"}):
    #      ...
    # else:
    #      ...
except (AttributeError, IndexError) as e:
    continue
```

And for part where you are trying to get text, a simply test could be enough in my opinion

Like:

```
if soup.find('p', {'class': "ConsolidationPeriod-e"}):
    text = soup.find('p', {'class': "ConsolidationPeriod-e"}).get_text()
else:
    text = soup.find('p', {'class': "ConsolidationPeriod"}).text
```

Or:

```
if soup.find('p', {'class': "regnumber-e"}):
    reg_title = soup.find('p', {'class': "regnumber-e"}).get_text()
elif soup.find('p', {'class': "regtitle-e"}):
    reg_title = soup.find('p', {'class': "regtitle-e"}).get_text()
else:
    reg_title = soup.find('p', {'class': "Yregnumber-e"}).get_text()
```